# Pass only some arguments to a function as a named list in R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, do.call

Given a function

```
 power <- function(x,a,b) b*x^a
```

I know that, instead of calling it with `power(c(1:10),2,1.5)`, I can invoke it with `do.call` using a named list, with

```
 parms=list(x=c(1:10),a=2,b=1.5)
 do.call("power",parms)
```

However, imagine I have different vectors `x` to be processed with the same values of `a` and `b`.  Unless I have missed something, it seems I cannot define a *partial* list `parms=list(a=2,b=1.5)` and then re-use such list with different values of `x`, something like

```
 power(c(1:10),parms)
```

or

```
 do.call("power",c(1:10),parms)
```

Comment: along the same lines as you are thinking - the following could work `do.call("power",list(x=c(1:10), a=2,b=1.5))`. Does that address your use case?

Comment: In order to reuse ```parms``` it should be something like ```do.call("power",append(list(x=c(1:10)),parms))``` but I wanted to know if there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

How about making the parameters which don't change as default arguments of the function.

```
power <- function(x,a = 2,b = 1.5) b*x^a

lapply(list(1:10, 11:20), power)

#[[1]]
# [1]   1.5   6.0  13.5  24.0  37.5  54.0  73.5  96.0 121.5 150.0

#[[2]]
# [1] 181.5 216.0 253.5 294.0 337.5 384.0 433.5 486.0 541.5 600.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
pmap(parms, power)
```